# prove if $f$ is bounded in [a,b] and integrable in every [a+$\epsilon$ , b] for every $\epsilon$ > 0 then $f$ integrable in [a,b]

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I've started with showing that the improper integral in [a,b] is the limit when t goes to a+ (I've said that t=a+ $\epsilon$ )
but now to say that the improper integral is defined I need to show that the limit exist and final.

Comment: Use upper and lower sums

Comment: $f$ is bounded, $m >= f >= M$ so the limit is bounded by
$(b-a)M$ and $(b-a)m$
is that enough?

Comment: Almost. When you have epsilon really small, the integral over the epsilon region is going to be small too because the function is bounded. Hence if the a b - e integral converges, you add only a small amount of mass (say M*epsilon ) by integrating over the rest of the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\sup_{[a,b]}| f|$.

We can assume $M>0$.

Given $\epsilon>0$ small enough.

$f$ is integrable at $[a+\frac{\epsilon}{4M},b]$ thus by Cauchy criterion,

there exist a partition $\sigma$ of $[a+\frac{\epsilon}{4M},b]$ such that

$$U(f,\sigma)-L(f,\sigma)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Put $$\Sigma=\sigma \cup\{a\}$$

then

$$U(f,\Sigma)-L(f,\Sigma)\le$$
$$2M\frac{\epsilon}{4M}+U(f,\sigma)-L(f,\sigma)$$
$$<\epsilon$$

done.